# How do I change the page size of a subreport in Crystal Reports? (SAP Crystal Reports 2016 SP 5)

Tags: crystal-reports

Here's what I want to change: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXQe2.jpg

Here's what I tried:

- Right click inside subreport / Page Setup / Increase "Horizontal"
- Right click inside main report / Page Setup / Increase "Horizontal"
- Change size of subreport object inside main report

None of these worked.. can you please let me know how to change the page size of a subreport?

Comment: (Pro tip: we prefer not to use [solved] devices in titles here. Just post a self-answer as you have done, and then when the system lets you, click the adjacent tick to mark your solution. We welcome self-answers!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED - I had to save, close and reopen Crystal Reports for the change to take effect.

Credit to Legmar from the CrystalReportsBook forum for the [answer](http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=13920).

Answer (score 0):

I did all the steps in your question, and last one below solved it for me.

-Right click inside subreport / Page Setup / Increase "Horizontal"

-Right click inside main report / Page Setup / Increase "Horizontal"

-Change size of subreport object inside main report.